# Why can't I create an instance of flash.text.StaticText?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

The [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StaticText.html) says: *"`You cannot create a StaticText object using ActionScript. Only the authoring tool can create a StaticText object. An attempt to create a new StaticText object generates an ArgumentError.`"*

Why is that? How does Flash Professional create `StaticText`, and why can't I do the same with AS3?

Comment: Why can't you just create your static texts with a simple TextField like anybody else?

Comment: StaticText is just a DisplayObject, with a readonly text property. It's the Flash Authoring tool that creates a graphical element (the text) and draws it onto the stage, like a circle or a square. Just use Textfield instead if you need to add text with AS3.

Comment: @Karma if you change your comment to an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StaticText is just a DisplayObject, with a readonly text property. It's the Flash Authoring tool that actually creates a graphical element (the text) and draws it onto the stage like a circle or a square.

Just use Textfield instead if you need to add text with AS3.

```
import  flash.text.TextField;

var myText:TextField = new TextField();
myText.text = "Hello World";
addChild(myText);
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you created the text with code, rather than on stage with the authoring tool, means that by definition, it is a dynamic text field, not a static text field.